# Hyper-V inside an Azure VM

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, azure

Our DevOps team created a VM instance in our Azure Cloud.

The O/S is "Windows Server 2016 Datacenter" version 10.0.14393

I want to run create a "nested" VM instance on this PC.

I tried enabling Hyper-V using the process described here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization

But when I went to start the VM I got a message

> Failed to start the virtual machine because one of the Hyper-V components is not running

[image: VM Error]

When I asked our DevOps team about it, they said

> The Azure VM is already a virtual machine running on physical server provided by MS and Hyper-V is only supported on physical boxes.

I'm not sure this is true.
Is it possible to enable Hyper-V inside an Azure VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested Virt is only available using the Dv3 and Ev3 VM sizes.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/